# Analogue of the "tail -f example.log" command in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, shell, tail

Is there a similar command in Windows?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command) for a whole bunch of suggestions.

Comment: It's in Cygwin and also in my C shell for Windows.  http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm